# Some irritations with ListView and DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

I've wrote the following C# and XAML Code:

```
namespace ListViewExample1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyColleague> myCollegues = new ObservableCollection<MyColleague>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        myCollegues.Add(new MyColleague() { Name = "Tim", Surname = "Meier" });
        myCollegues.Add(new MyColleague() { Name = "Martin", Surname = "Hansen" });
        myCollegues.Add(new MyColleague() { Name = "Oliver", Surname = "Drumm" });


        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyColleague> MyColleagues 
    {
        get { return this.myCollegues; }
    }
}

public class MyColleague
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Surname { get; set; }
}
}
```

XAML-Code:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource ListViewExample1:MainWindow}, Path=myCollegues}">
        <ListView.View >
            <GridView >
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Surname" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Surname}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView> 
</Grid>
```

Now I need to set the datacontext, but at this point I have some irritations. Which DataContext-Syntax is right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are dozens of ways to set `DataContext`; no one is inherently right.

It's worth noting that there's no reason to set `DataContext` on an items control at all if all you need is to bind one property (`ItemsSource`, in this case).  Setting `DataContext` simplifies binding multiple properties, because all of the bindings use the same context.

If you want to do data binding without *any* code-behind (as you said in a comment), the example you've chosen isn't very good, since you're creating the object in code-behind.  Try creating a class with a parameterless constructor, e.g.:

```
public class MyColleagueCollection : ObservableCollection<MyColleague>
{
   public MyColleagueCollection()
   {
       Add(new MyColleague() { Name = "Tim", Surname = "Meier" });
       Add(new MyColleague() { Name = "Martin", Surname = "Hansen" });
       Add(new MyColleague() { Name = "Oliver", Surname = "Drumm" });
   }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
<ListView>
   <ListView.ItemsSource>
      <local:MyColleagueCollection/>
   </ListView.ItemsSource>
   ...
</ListView>
```

Or you could set the `DataContext`, and set the `ItemsSource` to `"{Binding}"`.  Or create the object in a resource dictionary, and bind using `StaticResource`.

You could also create your collection as a property (not a field, as x0r correctly points out) of the `Window` class and do this:

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"...
```

which now makes the `Window` itself the data context object, allowing any element in the window to bind to its properties directly without using `RelativeSource`.

Or (we're nowhere near done), you can give the window a name, and then bind to it by name:

```
<ListView ItemsSource=`{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=MyCollection}"...
```

Let's not even get into using an `ObjectDataProvider`.

What most people end up doing - this is as close to a "right" answer as you're going to find - is creating a view model class for the main window, instantiating it in the window's constructor, and setting the window's `DataContext` to that object.  From that point on, any view that the main window displays is bound to a property of that view model.  See Josh Smith's article on the Model/View/ViewModel pattern for a really good worked example.

Binding and data contexts are *incredibly versatile*.  This of course also means that there are a lot of things you can get wrong.  It goes with the territory.  Once you understand them, though, you rarely run into real problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive explanation. But, you said that DataContext must not be set in my case. Without set the Context, the data are not displayed.

Comment: @hat does the binding to `ItemsSource` look like?

Comment: Thats it: `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyColleagues}">`

Comment: You need more than just a `Path`; you need to give the binding some way of finding the source.  The examples I gave using `ElementName` or `StaticResource` or `RelativeSource` all do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your binding to `myCollegues` can't work, because you bind to a field. You have to bind to the property, which is `MyColleagues` in your case.

The simplest solution to set your `DataContext` would be in code-behind, assuming that `MainWindow.xaml` contains the `ListView`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    [...]    
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Instead of keeping your data in code-behind, a better solution would be to use the MVVM approach. There you keep your data in a separate class, and then set the `DataContext` to an instance of this class.

To bind in XAML use the following syntax:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollegues}" 
              DataContext="{Binding Path=., Mode=FindAncestor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewExample1:MainWindow}}}">
```

Comment: Thank your for your replay, but this results in 'Failed to create a 'RelativeSourceMode' from the text 'ListViewExample1:MainWindow'

Comment: Yes, that is a simple solution, but I want to try DataBinding without code-behind in this case.

Comment: @Kai: Prepend `AncestorType=`, the [constructor of RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597595.aspx) expects a [mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode.aspx) (which can be ommitted when setting [AncestorType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestortype.aspx)).

Comment: @H.B: Thank you very much. Following XAML works like a charme: `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyColleagues}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewExample1:MainWindow}}}"`

Comment: Note also that the field myCollegues is public and can be changed, since there is no PropertyChanged when this happens your listview will no update your binding. You should put myCollegues private and readonly.